# How do I set workbook variable based on a filename I has as a string variable? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set a workbook variable "Detailwb" as a workbook that the user selects with the Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) function but I am receiving the following error msg: "Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range" on the last line of the code below. I know that the workbooks call should be in this format; Workbooks("file name") but I want the program to call whatever .xlsx file the user selects. I'm just not sure what the proper syntax/method is to accomplish this.

Here's an excerpt;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Define All Variables
Dim GCell As Range
Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
Dim Detailwb As Workbook
Dim Timewb As Workbook
Dim MyDetailReport As String
Dim MyTimeSheet As String
Dim MySheet As String
Dim ProjNum As String
Dim PhaseCode As String
Dim Hours As String
Dim WkEndDate As String
Dim FindRowNumber As Long
Dim FindColumn As Long


'Define Workbooks
Set Timewb = ThisWorkbook


'Find source file
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Select Daily Report File to Import"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = "W:\PDX - Mechanical Construction\Operations\Detailing\Daily Tracking Logs\"
    fDialog.Filters.Clear
    fDialog.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx"
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
        MyDetailReport = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyDetailReport & MyTimeSheet
Set Detailwb = Workbooks(MyDetailReport)
```

Comment: Yeah, what is MyTimeSheet?  It's not defined in this subroutine.  Is it a global variable?  Try removing "& MyTimeSheet" and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks.Open returns a reference to the opened workbook, so you only need one line for this:

```
Set Detailwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyDetailReport & MyTimeSheet)
```

What's `MyTimeSheet` doing though?

Comment: MyTimeSheet is a different string variable that houses the name of the workbook already open and does not need to be included here. I already figured out a slicker way to accomplish this;                    
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyDetailReport
Set Detailwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count), Thanks for your response though.